# ISim shows U for all flip flops outputs

Tags: vhdl, fpga

When I try to simulate my VHDL code with ISIM it shows onlys `U` for all outputs.

That just made up of three cascaded D-type flip flops.

**And here is my VHDL code:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity az_4_2 is
    Port ( clk: in std_logic;
            X : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Ain : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Bin : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Aout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Bout : out  STD_LOGIC;
              Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Y : out  STD_LOGIC;
              reset : in std_logic);
end az_4_2;

architecture Behavioral of az_4_2 is
begin


process(clk, reset, Ain, Bin, Cin, X)
begin

if (reset = '1') then
Y <= '0';

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '0') then
Y <= '0';

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '1') then
Y <= '0';

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '1') and (Cin = '0') then
Y <= '0';

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '1') and (Cin = '1') then
if (x = '0') then
Y <= '0';
else
Y <= '1';
end if;

elsif (Ain = '1') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '0') then
if (x = '0') then
Y <= '0';
else
Y <= '1';
end if;

end if;


if(rising_edge(clk)) then


if (reset = '1') then
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '0') then
if (x = '0') then
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';
else
Aout <= '1';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';
end if;

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '1') then
if (x = '0') then
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '1';
Cout <= '0';
else
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '1';
Cout <= '1';
end if;

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '1') and (Cin = '0') then
if (x = '0') then
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';
else
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '1';
Cout <= '1';
end if;

elsif (Ain = '0') and (Bin = '1') and (Cin = '1') then
if (x = '0') then
Aout <= '1';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';
else
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '1';
Cout <= '1';
end if;

elsif (Ain = '1') and (Bin = '0') and (Cin = '0') then
if (x = '0') then
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '0';
Cout <= '0';
else
Aout <= '0';
Bout <= '1';
Cout <= '1';

end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**And here is my TEST_BENCH:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY tb_az_4 IS
END tb_az_4;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_az_4 IS 

COMPONENT az_4
    Port ( clk: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            X : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Ain : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Bin : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Aout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Bout : out  STD_LOGIC;
              Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Y : out  STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

   --Inputs
   signal clk, reset : std_logic := '0';

    --BiDirs
   signal X, Ain, Bin, Cin, Aout, Bout, Cout, Y : std_logic;

begin
   uut: az_4 PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
             reset => reset,
          X => X,
          Ain => Ain,
             Aout => Aout,
             Bin => Bin,
          Bout => Bout,
             Cin => Cin,
             Cout => Cout,
          Y => Y
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
clock_process :process
begin
     clk <= '0';
     wait for 5 ns;
     clk <= '1';
     wait for 5 ns;
end process;


-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin        
   -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
   reset <= '1';    
    wait for 10 ns;
    reset <= '0';   
   Ain <= '0';
   Bin <= '0';
    Cin <= '0';
    x <= '0'; 

   wait;
end process;

END behavior;
```

So why this is happened? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check if you are simulating the test bench, not the component itself. And please fix the indentation in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During elaboration a component instantiation of component declaration is associated with a particular design entity. This can either be done explicitly - by a configuration specification in the enclosing block declarative region or a configuration declaration providing a binding indication, or implicitly by default binding.

Lacking both a configuration specification and a configuration declaration in your example a default binding indication is attempted during elaboration. The component name in the component instantiation statement is searched for (az_4).

The search finds the first of:

- An entity declaration that has the same simple name and is directly visible (through a use clause of the form L.all; where L is a reference library).
- An entity as above that would be directly visible barring a visible component declaration with the same simple name hiding the entity.
- An entity declaration denoted by L.C where L is the target library logical name where the component C is declared.

In your case the search did not find az_4, noting you do provide an az_4_2.

Your uut in the testbench architecture body is unbound in a default binding indication without an entity named az_4 being directly visible.

There are three ways to cure this.

1. You can make the four names match (the entity name in the entity az_4_2, it's matching architecture body, the component declaration and component instantiation statement in the testbench architecture body) and count on default binding.
2. You can provide a binding indication as configuration specification as a testbench architecture declarative item:

   ```
    for uut: az_4                    -- ADDED configuration  specification
        use entity work.az_4_2;
   begin
      uut: az_4 port map (
   ```
3. Or you can provide a binding indication in a configuration declaration, which hardly seems worthwhile for a single component instantiation.

I've checked to see your code will analyze, elaborate and simulate with the first two methods, noting your testbench won't stop simulation until simulation time reaches TIME'HIGH without implementation intervention (such as running the simulation for a set time interval). The clock runs continuously.

Providing the configuration specification shown above produces:

[image: tb_az_4.png]

Which shows the binding indication worked and that your testbench stim_proc process isn't fully developed as yet.